# Can a minio bucket be set up so that stored objects are immutable and non-versioned?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, retention

Is it possible to set up a minio bucket so that files are not overwritten, nor versioned? Conceptually what I want is:

```
$ mc cp myobject.bin myminio/mybucket // should be ok if 'myobject.bin' does not already exist in the bucket
$ mc cp myobject.bin myminio/mybucket // an error should be returned and 'myobject.bin' is not uploaded again
```

I have played around with the 'legalhold' option but enabling that on a bucket will also enable versioning. This results in that the two commands above will both succeed and 'myobject.bin' is stored as two 'consecutive' versions. For my use case it would be better if an object stored in the bucket is immutable, never-changing and not versioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no - immutability is guaranteed through versioning, and object retention/legal hold gives WORM protection on this version for the duration you specify.